# Is there a more sophisticated way of saying "surprisingly?"

Tags: word-usage, grammar, word-choice

I am writing a paper for my English class, but I don't want to use colloquial speech. Is there a way of saying "surprisingly" in a more sophisticated way? Thank you.

Comment: Can you show us an example sentence where "surprisingly" is used?

Answer (score 1):

"Surprisingly" is not particularly colloquial or informal. From Thesaurus.com, they list the following:

> Synonyms for surprisingly:
>
> especially, exceptionally, notably, principally, specially, unusually, peculiarly, decidedly, distinctly, explicitly, expressly, in particular, individually, markedly, and outstandingly.

If you Google "synonyms for surprisingly" you will find additional examples. However, don't be afraid to use "surprisingly" in your essay if its use is warranted.